# Does the answer of the Nygma's riddle in S03E04 have a second meaning?

Tags: analysis, gotham

Riddle said by Edward Nygma to Penguin in Episode 4 of Season 3 of Gotham:

> I can't be bought, but I can be stolen with a glance. I'm worthless to
>   one, but priceless to two.

The answer should be "love". What I'm not sure is whether this was a declaration of love between Nygma and the Penguin or anything else...

[Some people](http://www.wijily.com/tumblr/blog/lucalli/p/151652961017) theorize about a gay relationship hidden there.

Answer (score 3):

Nah he's saying Penguin needs the love of the people to win the election in a way that feels deserving and he can't buy love.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be bought but I can be stolen with a glance. I am worthless to one but priceless to two. what am I? I'm love. What Nygma is trying to say by the riddle is that he does need the love of the people of Gotham.